# How to parse milliseconds to date in React-native

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting date from in this format "/Date(1471846675177+0000)/"
I have done this :

```
var longToDate=function(millisec){
    var length=millisec.length-7;
    var date=millisec.substring(6,length);
    return (new Date(millisec.substring(6,length)).toUTCString());
}
```

But it is showing "invalid date". 
Can someone tell me the reason for it  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `parseInt`

```
var longToDate = function(millisec) {
    var length = millisec.length - 7;
    var date = parseInt(millisec.substring(6,length));
    return (new Date(date).toUTCString());
}
```

Comment: If we do this, then this error is returned

TypeError: millisec.substring is not a function. (In 'millisec.substring(6, length)', 'millisec.substring' is undefined)

can you help in this matter ?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to convert to string milisec

```
 var longToDate = function(millisec) {
var length = millisec.length-7;
var date = parseInt((millisec.toString()).substring(6,length));
return (new Date(date).toUTCString());
```

}